# How to save to localStorage from textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to save an email entered to textarea in `localStorage`. I see the placeholder "your gmail address" when I load the page, but when I enter a value and click "save" nothing happens. I don't see the alert or the console verifying that text is saved. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head><title>Extension Options</title></head>
<body>
<textarea id="user" style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 250px; height: 20px">
</textarea><br />
<button id="save">Save</button>
<!--<button id="save">Clear</button>-->

<script type="text/javascript">

//check if "user" is in localStorage

if (localStorage["user"])
{
    var user = localStorage["user"] ;
    document.getElementById("user").value = user ;
    alert("you are already a user")
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("user").placeholder = "your gmail address" ;
    console.log("user no found in localStorage")
}

//save entered gmail address
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener
{
    "click", function ()
    {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value ;
        //localStorage["user"] = user ;
        localStorage.setItem("user", user) ;
        alert("gmail id saved") ;
        console.log("gmail id saved")
    } , false
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should definitely see a syntax error in the console.

Comment: @pimvdb, yes, you right, I tried it again with curly braces and I saw the error message in the console.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your addEventListener function is being used incorrectly. It should be used like this:

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function ()
    {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value ;
        //localStorage["user"] = user ;
        localStorage.setItem("user", user) ;
        alert("gmail id saved") ;
        console.log("gmail id saved")
    } , false);
```

[MDN docs on element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

[Working demo with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7KLEd/)